# react-router: Append a string to the end of the address bar without affecting app or router?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, url-routing

I have a route like this:

```
<Route path="lookbook" component={Lookbook} onEnter={onPageEnter}>
  <Route path=":photoIdentifier" component={PhotoDetailsModal} onEnter={onPageEnter}/>
</Route>
```

Which enables a path like so: *myapp.com/lookbook/45*

If the :photoIdentifier '45' is an ID of a photo, and is used to gather data for that corresponding photo, **is there there a way to append the title string to the end of the url without re-routing or affecting the app**?

So basically the path would look something like *myapp.com/lookbook/45/cool-photo-title*

Of course I would set up a route to accomodate this new path, but in terms of navigating internally, I just want to hold the photo IDs for creating the paths in my Link components, and append the titles after the fact for a more English-friendly shareable URL.

Comment: What about ```<Route path=":photoIdentifier/:photoTitle" component={PhotoDetailsModal} onEnter={onPageEnter}/>```?

Comment: That can work, however it does not answer my original question. Internally, I want to carry around ID data in order to build my Link components. Therefore my Link components would look something like `<Link to={{pathname: "/lookbook/"+data.id}}>`. This will allow users to navigate 'next' & 'previous' photos. However, whichever photo they are viewing, I want to append the title of the photo to the end of the URL so its a more readable shareable URL.

Comment: u can make that name optional by putting it in the `()`, like this: `<Route path=":photoIdentifier(/:photoTitle)" component={PhotoDetailsModal} onEnter={onPageEnter}/>` now this photoTitle is optional param, no need to create new route for that, when you want to append name just append at the end or ignore if you don't want.

Comment: Yes, I realise that this type of Route can accommodate my use case, however I am talking about appending a string to the address bar programatically.

Comment: @connected_user I know this is an old post, but did you find any solution for this? I'm looking to do the same thing and can't find anything too useful.

Answer (score 0):

You can try optional params, i think, it will fulfill your requirement. Try this:

```
<Route path=":photoIdentifier(/:photoTitle)" component={PhotoDetailsModal} onEnter={onPageEnter}/>
```

Now this `photoTitle` is a optional param, use it when you want to show the title otherwise you can ignore also.

You can use both the links:

```
{{pathname: "/lookbook/"+data.id+"/"+photoTitle}}
```

or

```
{{pathname: "/lookbook/"+data.id}}
```

It will open the same page, and photoTitle will appear in the url.

You can use query also, without affecting the original route, like this:

```
{{pathname: "/lookbook/"+data.id+"/"+"title="+photoTitle}}
```

Comment: I am aware about all of this. However this does not deal with my question. I guess my actual question is: How do I append a string to the end of the address bar without affecting the router or reloading the page or doing anything?

Comment: without affecting route, in that case you can you query , but for that you have to use some key along with photo name.